# Create SQL Server tables and stored procedures in one script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

I have a SQL script that is setting up two database tables with their keys and constraints without any problem. I won't include the whole code but the 'skeleton' of it looks like this:

```
 BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [table] (

)

CREATE TABLE [table2] (

)

ALTER TABLE table...

ALTER TABLE table2....


END
```

I am stuck trying to add stored procedures to this script though, ideally I would like to include this all within the same script. Could someone tell me how to include the following stored procedure into the above script?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
    @x int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table
END
GO
```

I have tried putting it towards the end of the script and have also tried with and without the BEGIN, END and GO tags but I keep getting an error that says 'incorrect syntax near PROCEDURE'.

Comment: Are you trying to create a sql script? I'm confused with "schema" word.

Comment: Yes sorry maybe that is what I meant! Am new to SQL

Comment: If you have an error when you add the `GO` to your script there must be another problem. I know you said the script was long but perhaps you could post the section causing the problem? Also, have a read of the documentation on `GO` if you are unsure of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
USE BDNAME
GO

 BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [table] (

)

CREATE TABLE [table2] (

)

ALTER TABLE table...

ALTER TABLE table2....


END


USE BDNAME
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Test
    @x int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table
END

GO
```

Comment: Did you mean put GO at the end of table creation and before stored procedure? Gave that a try and got 'incorrect syntax near GO'

Comment: this is for sybase ase, mysql, sql server, what?

Comment: Apologies, the problem was coming from how the script was being called, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using BEGIN END, put GO between all your Statements like Create, Alter. Also I would like to inform you that putting GO will create blocks in your script, so if you create some local variable in one block, it is not accessible in another.

```
 CREATE Table Table1(
     --Your Code
 )

 GO

 CREATE PROCEDURE Test
      @x int
 AS
 BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Table1
 END

 GO

 --Continue your script
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean put GO after each code block. After doing that I got the following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: It would be easy if you can post your actual script, may be initial code blocks